# AutocompleteTextView suggestion list goes up

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

possible duplicates 
[Android : autocompletetextview, suggestion list displays above the textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668473/760489)

I am fully trying to display suggestion list overlapping on keyboard when suggestion list scroll by user but it always open up side.

here I am getting this way

[image]

here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sl"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SuggestionListActivity" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

here is my main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <TextView android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is testing for the auto complete textview in this application to display suggestion list overlapping on keyboard." />

    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Search"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:dropDownHeight="300dp"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete" android:singleLine="true"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

what to do in this code to display the suggestion over keyboard when list was focus.

Comment: i have a doubt that are you entering any text in the AutoCompleteTextView ? because there is no data but list is displayed!!

Comment: Why do you want it to be on the softkeyboard?...it wont allow user to type more characters right....like if there are 10000 strings with "he..." and only 5 strings with "hez..." better allow user to type "z" instead of scrolling 10000 items...when i was using autocomplete in my app i got the same problem, but i think this is the best approach considering the low screen size devices

Comment: if you want to display suggestions with out entering any data means when onclick on the AutoCompleteTextView, then disable the soft keyboard and implement on click event for the AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: I have requirement that when user click/tap on autocomplete then display the list with all data having fix size so user can select from the list, if user can type no problem it care itself to display list which are containing that charater

Comment: In Gingerbread phones and before the popup window is calculated depending on the available space. So if  there is more space available at top then the popup will show above. But Post Gingerbread this has been fixed to show the autocomplete suggestion only at the bottom. So the same app will work correctly on ICS phones.

Comment: have you got answer of above ?

Comment: any fix for this thread ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had this problem before. For me, there was more screen space above the `AutocompleteTextView` than below (testing on a "normal" device), so the list opened upwards. I adjusted my layout slightly so that there was more space below the `AutocompleteTextView` and it started opening downwards. That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: @MaheshSuthar: Showing code won't help you. The point is that there needs to be more space below the dropdown than above it. So, however you achieve that is up to you.

Answer (score 7):

You can either adjust the layout so that there is more space below the `AutoCompleteTextView`

or

you can change the dropdown height `android:dropDownHeight` and set some high value,
this would work when its inside a `scrollView` and the `AutoCompleteTextView` is near the top.

To display the list of options on focus do something like this

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
            autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
        }
    }
});
```

This would display a list of options when the user focuses on the `AutoCompleteTextView`

Comment: I already set this 300dp for dropDownHeight and it'll goes always upward and also display list when it focus by this focuschangelistener. The problem is for small device.

Comment: Did you try putting it in a scroll view and moving the `AutoCompleteTextview` near the top ?

Comment: actually I have put this in tab so on top of tab are available and that much space is there so I have test this to place this control with some top margin

Answer (score 7):

The trick is to ensure that the desired drop-down height is never larger than the available space below. My approach is to create a subclass that overrides `showDropDown`:

```
public class DownOnlyAutoCompleteTextView extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {

    private final static int MINIMAL_HEIGHT = 50;

    public DownOnlyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DownOnlyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DownOnlyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void showDropDown() {
        Rect displayFrame = new Rect();
        getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayFrame);

        int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
        getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);

        int bottom = locationOnScreen[1] + getHeight();
        int availableHeightBelow = displayFrame.bottom - bottom;
        if (availableHeightBelow >= MINIMAL_HEIGHT) {
            setDropDownHeight(availableHeightBelow);
        }

        super.showDropDown();
    }
}
```

Then use this in your layout, e.g.:

```
<your.package.DownOnlyAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/auto_complete_text_view"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:hint="AutoComplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Adjust `MINIMAL_HEIGHT` to fit your requirements -- if there's no or very little space below, it's probably better not to force the issue.

**EDIT**

[As mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406773/illegalargumentexception-in-autocompletetextview-showdropdown), passing a negative number to `setDropDownHeight` will trigger an exception in some Android versions. As long as you define a `MINIMAL_HEIGHT` greater than zero, that should not be a problem.

Comment: May I know the `availableHeightBelow` is in px or dp?

Comment: Pixels, I believe. Though it shouldn't really matter, as long as all the APIs are agreed on the unit...

Comment: I use your code and it crash on certain devices on Android 8.0.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406773/illegalargumentexception-in-autocompletetextview-showdropdown

Comment: @user2872856 Good Point!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution

```
private final static int DELAY_MS = 500;
autoCompletionTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            autoCompletionTextView.requestFocus();
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> autoCompletionTextView.showDropDown(), DELAY_MS);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

After keyboard shows up suggestion list is listed above yout AutoCompletionTextView.

Answer (score 1):

use:   `android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content" in AutoCompleteTextView`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the `android:dropDownHeight="100dp"` to the `AutoCompleteTextView` tag in your layout file will be the best solution I guess! it will simply control the height of drop down hight and allow us to scroll!

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/acetxt_assignclient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:dropDownHeight="100dp">
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found if you are using a nested scroll view, it is more prone to open the view above or below as it sees fit where as when you are using a regular scroll view it opens below.

Answer (score -2):

Set Full Layout containing Autocompletetextview inside Scrollview

This will solve your problem!