# Showing dropdown of AutoComplete below

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout in  which I have autoComplete edit text with some suggestions.
The image below is its normal behaviour until keyboard slides in.

[image]

after the keyboard comes the dropdown goes above the field which hides my TO: field. As shown below.
[image]

What should I do to get the dropdown below even when the keyboard slides up.
I want the result to be like this.

[image]

Thanks...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554766/autocompletetextview-suggestion-list-goes-up#comment15928713_11554766

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by hiding the upper layout when key board is shown and focus is on this edit text. As soon as the keyboard is slided_out the upper layout is visible again which bring back the original screen.
For detecting the keyboard slide_in/slide_out i used something like this.

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView()
                            .getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its
                                            // probably a keyboard...
                        if (searchText.isFocused()) {
                            //keyboard is shown
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (searchText.isFocused()) {
                            //Keyboard is hidden.
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```