# IllegalArgumentException in AutoCompleteTextView showDropDown

Tags: android

I received this crash report in Google Play Console which I myself never experience.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.setHeight (ListPopupWindow.java:541)
  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownHeight (AutoCompleteTextView.java:414)
  at .MyEditText.showDropDown (MyEditText.java:44)
  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter (AutoCompleteTextView.java:1086)
  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete (AutoCompleteTextView.java:1068)
  at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage (Filter.java:285)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:172)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6637)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I am using this `showDropDown` method to leave the space of 50 dp from the bottom of screen so that the drop down will not cover my Admob ads on the bottom.

```
public void showDropDown() {
    Rect displayFrame = new Rect();
    getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayFrame);

    int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
    getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);

    int bottom = locationOnScreen[1] + getHeight();
    int availableHeightBelow = displayFrame.bottom - bottom;
    Resources r = getResources();
    int bannerHeight = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    int downHeight = availableHeightBelow - bannerHeight;
    setDropDownHeight(downHeight);

    super.showDropDown();
}
```

From Google Play Console, this crash only affects Mi A1 and Mate 10 Pro running Android 8.0. I do not experience this crash on emulator running Android 8.0.

This is the desired effect:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time being, I added code to check whether `downHeight > 0` to prevent this crash.

```
public void showDropDown() {
        Rect displayFrame = new Rect();
        getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayFrame);

        int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
        getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);

        int bottom = locationOnScreen[1] + getHeight();
        int availableHeightBelow = displayFrame.bottom - bottom;
        Resources r = getResources();
        int bannerHeight = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
        int downHeight = availableHeightBelow - bannerHeight;
        if (downHeight > 0) {
            setDropDownHeight(downHeight);
        } else {
            setDropDownHeight(300);
        }

        super.showDropDown();
    }
```

Comment: What is the role of `bannerHeight` exactly? Does it just set something like marginBottom for the dropdown list? Can I remove it from my code or it is related to the crash?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the IllegalArgumentException is thrown [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.java#541).
If you track earlier versions of Android ([N](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/core/java/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.java#541) and earlier) that defensive code does not exist.
Based on your computations, the height could be negative. I think you'd need a different way to achieve the desired result. How does your layout look like?

Comment: I have added a screenshot.  I just want to leave a space of 50 dp from the bottom of screen.

Comment: Looking at your computations, if availableHeightBelow is less than 50 dp you would get this exception (you could somehow try to reproduce it by creating a really long list of suggestion in the autocomplete?)

Comment: I feel the computation is incorrect. You're setting the height of the drop down to height below - 50dp, I think you need to set it to the whole height available in the window - (height of the keyboard + 50dp)