# how to hide soft-keyboard behind the View like Gmail app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, autosuggest

I had implemented auto-suggestion functionality using `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` successfully and everything is working fine except **i'm not able to display auto-suggestion list above the soft-keyboard**.

**Android Gmail app has the same functionality. [see below image]**

[image]

**Question:**

> I want the exact functionality, want to a display a suggestion list on
>   the soft-keyboard but i don't have any clue how to achieve this. My
>   suggestion list is always hidden behind the soft-keyboard.
>
> How to show auto-suggestion list above the soft-keyboard like Gmail
>   app?

I had tried playing with different `android:imeOptions` and different xml attributes and did a lot of searching but nothing helped.

Is there any public Api or XML attribute is available to do so?
Does anyone have any clue or idea about how to achieve this.

Code Structure : My fragment opens an `AlertDialog` which contains `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` where i'm implementing auto-suggest.

Any help or suggestion which leads to the right direction, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: same here... seems device-dependent. It doesn't work on sony devices. Could you solve the problem?

Comment: I'm still in search of the answer, no clue yet.

Comment: I couldn't solve it like the way on the picture above, but I did something. I set the height of the drop-down list to 100dp and now the drop-down list is not behing the keyboard. It is above and scrollable, but only 2 lines are visible at the same time... But better than nothing.

Comment: For me the suggestion list is displayed above the keyboard by default. However I want it behind it :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340802/listview-is-over-keyboard-and-not-behind-when-i-start-scrolling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668473/android-autocompletetextview-suggestion-list-displays-above-the-textview