# Android AutoCompleteTextView DropDown Position

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using following code for auto complete however, dropdown items comes above the `AutoCompleteTextView`. I want it to show up beneath the `AutoCompleteTextView`. How can I do that?

```
package com.example.autocomplete;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium","Belgam","Bellam", "France Belgium", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/countries_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:dropDownHeight="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="AutoCompleteTextView" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add your full layout xml?

Comment: Edited. Can you look at it, now, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like this must work:

```
android:dropDownHeight="100dp"
```

Founded here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7648028/1723525

**Edit:**

I tried with a new Activity and the suggestions ara shown below. Maybe you have to change the dropDownHeight to 150dp because you have marginTop of 100dp. I guess that the dropDownHeight must be higher than the Y position (= padding + margin). Let me know if it works.

Comment: Maybe the point is that you have to make it small enough to display it in the space. Otherwise it just pick the bigger one.

Answer (score 10):

Set height of dropdown and set space between dropdown and edittext. Dropdown will display above and below view in dropdownanchor. Height = 200dp, dropdown will not overlap keyboard.

```
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dropdownAutoCompleteTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp">
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/autoTextViewState"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:digits="@string/get_started_petname_digits"
                        android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/dropdownAutoCompleteTextView"
                        android:dropDownHeight="200dp"
                        android:hint="Colorado"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textCapWords"
                        android:maxLength="15"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editZipCode"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the `android:dropDownAnchor`, `android:dropDownHorizontalOffset`, `android:dropDownVerticalOffset` and maybe others on the `AutoCompleteTextView` in your layout. For more info [AutocompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Comment: android:dropDownVerticalOffset is what exactly I need. Thanks dude!

Comment: @MahmoudElshamy what is the exact use of `android:dropDownVerticalOffset` ?

Answer (score 4):

Let's understand how dropdown view will be rendered. In the fact, it's **PopupWindow** and it decide position (above or below compare with view archor) by method [findDropDownPosition](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.0.0_r33/core/java/android/widget/PopupWindow.java). Comment of this method said that:

> Positions the popup window on screen. When the popup window is too tall
>         to fit under the anchor, a parent scroll view is seeked and scrolled up
>         to reclaim space. If scrolling is not possible or not enough, the popup
>         window gets moved on top of the anchor.
>         The results of positioning are placed in {@code outParams}.

I've search serveral days but no any solutions really work in case you want handle dropdown's position (my case is in DialogFragment). 
This is my experience after serveral days, you can (cheat) code to fix this problem:

- Use `android:dropDownAnchor` to set anchor of dropdown to show, it's worked but UI is seem be too strange
- Use `setDropDownVerticalOffset(offset: Int)` again, it's worked but again, UI is too strange
- Set `android:dropDownHeight` to higher than height of (above or below) space, result will be the same as 2 ways above

Answer (score 3):

Add dropdownheight as well as dropdownanchor, will work surely.

```
android:dropDownAnchor="@id/yourIdOfViewOnTop"
android:dropDownHeight="100dp"
```