# How to create a Custom Drop down with Autocomplete feature in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to create a Custom  Drop down with Autocomplete feature in xamarin forms. Till now what I found is that I can achieve this only using Syncfusion.  But I don't want to use Syncfusion. In most of the code in xamarin forms they are using picker as the drop-down. But I won't be able to get the autocomplete feature for dropdown if I'm using picker. I need something like this

https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/combobox

I don't have any clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: custom renderer's of course using native iOS and Android

Comment: @G.hakim can you give me an example?

Comment: For Android you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401412/android-autocompletetextview-dropdown-position

Comment: For iOS check this https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look this library it support all platforms using Xamarin.forms https://github.com/XamFormsExtended/Xfx.Controls.

```
<ScrollView>
     <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  Padding="10"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
             <controls:CustomCombobox x:Name="listView_Countries" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                  PlaceHolder="{Binding [RelativeInfo_Relationship]}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding countryItems}"
                                  ItemDisplay="Description"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding FirstRelativeRelationship}"
                                  Margin="20,1,20,1" />
```

In here ItemsSource="{Binding countryItems}" // here you can bind your itemsource

```
public YourPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
    countryManager = new CountryManager();
    countryItems = countryManager.GetCountriesList().ToList();
    listView_Countries.ItemsSource = countryItems; }
```

Comment: Actually I needed something similar to this. Instead of displaying the email id. I need to see a list of country or list of state which is being hard coded. I'll attach a screenshot in my question for better understanding.